# ConfigError: The project '' is not a valid java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am working on an older project that requires JDK 14.0.2 and Gradle 6.3. It is not feasible to upgrade my project to a more recent JDK at this time.  I'm the only developer using VSCode, everyone else on the team is using intellij so i'm on my own with this issue. When I try to build my project using VSCode I get the ConfigError: The project 'myProject' is not a valid java project.  I can build my project fine using command line so long as my JAVA_HOME is 14.0.2.  I know the vscode debugger requires JDK 17+ but from the documentation it appears I can run applications that require older versions but clearly I'm doing something wrong.  Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
    "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "automatic",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Users/damorga/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"],
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-14",
            "path": "/Users/damorga/.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.2-open",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "/Users/damorga/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": false
}
```

I've tried changing JAVA_HOME to 17+ versions and I get different errors.  I've also tried using more recent versions of Gradle to no avail.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation to create the java project?  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_creating-a-source-code-file

Comment: I did, it didn't seem to make any difference.  VSCode still does not recognize my project as a Java project nor does it recognize any of my files as project files and only reports syntax errors.  I cannot get this to work in Intellij either.